# Show only checked boxes in DataGridView

Tags: vb.net, datagridview

I am returning SQL results into a DataGridView and have run into a problem.  I have an option on my form to only show checked values but can't get it working.  Here's my code:

```
    For x As Integer = dgvAutogrow.Rows.Count - 1 To dgvAutogrow.Rows.Count
        If dgvAutogrow.Rows(x).Cells("checked").Value = False Then
            dgvAutogrow.Rows.Remove(dgvAutogrow.Rows(x))
        End If
    Next
```

Here's what part of my DataGridView looks like.  I want an event to occur that shows only values that have the check box checked.

[image: .netError]

When I debug I get the following error:

[image: .netError]

Any suggestions on what to change?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to cast the cell as `DataGridViewCheckBoxCell` and then test the value like this:

```
For x As Integer = dgvAutogrow.Rows.Count - 1 To 0 Step -1    
    Dim cel as DataGridViewCheckBoxCell
    cel = CType(dgvAutogrow.Rows(x).Cells("YourColumnName"), DataGridViewCheckBoxCell)
    If cel.Value = False Then
        dgvAutogrow.Rows.Remove(dgvAutogrow.Rows(x))
    End If
Next
```

Also, you had an `ArgumentException` because the column you specified doesn´t exist, you need to change that.

Comment: Why the downvote? This solution fits the question.
Since I cannot add a comment to other answers, please change `.Cells("checked")` to `.Cells("IsPercentGrowth")` or an exception occurs.

Comment: Where's your x coming from? Also before you edited it, it didn't work. Also why would he need to change the cells name, it should be the one he's using ... Why would he need to change it to  IsPercentGrowth?

Comment: Not only was that an issue, there was an issue removing the row because his loop was wrong, you didn't address that issue either... So your answer isn't fit for the questions at hand...

Comment: That is correct, I edited my answer. However the OP needs to change the column name, otherwise it results in the `ArgumentException` he posted.

Comment: But I do know that, he posted the picture of the exception :)

Comment: Got an InvalidOperationException: "Uncommitted new row cannot be deleted."

Comment: That happens because you are trying to remove the last row, which has not been commited yet. Is the user allowed to add rows? If not, you can set the property `AllowUserToAddRows` to `False`.

Comment: That was it. I set the property to false and it worked. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

**Code is tried and tested.**

You can try this. We need to cast the cell as a `DataGridViewCheckBoxCell`and change your loop...

```
  For x As Integer = dgvAutogrow.Rows.Count - 1 To 0 Step -1
        If CType(dgvAutogrow.Rows(x).Cells("checked"), DataGridViewCheckBoxCell).Value = False Then
            dgvAutogrow.Rows.Remove(dgvAutogrow.Rows(x))
        End If
  Next
```